# How do i get a single value from a row in my datatable

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatable

I am using the jquery plugin DATATABLE.

I want to get a single value from a selected row in my datatable (the ID) but i dont how to do so. The value should be saved and given to a textbox.

Here is my Code:

```
var oTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable();
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php?method=fetchdata',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(s){
    console.log(s);
            oTable.fnClearTable();
                for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                 oTable.fnAddData([
                            s[i][0],
                            s[i][1],
                            s[i][2],
                            s[i][3],
                            s[i][4],
                                   ]);                                     
                                }

    },
    error: function(e){
       console.log(e.responseText);
    }
});

$('#dataTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');

}
else {
    oTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

}
```

Hopefully someone can help me!

Comment: Doesn't `this.id` work???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For the most part, you question looked pretty good, I just had to remove a stray line that didn't appear to be relevant (at the end). You appear to be using a jQuery plugin though, I'd recommend linking to it within your question as that appears to be an important piece to this question.

Answer (score 0):

in php:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$row = mysql_query("select * from _yourtable_ where id='$id'");
...
```

in the js:
You must send id to the file process.php by POST or GET method:

```
id = $('#textBoxSelector').val();
$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php?method=fetchdata&id='+id,
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(s){
        console.log(s);
        ...
    }
 });
```

Comment: Sorry but i think you misunderstood my question. I am working with jquery plugin datatable and i want to get a single value when i select a row and save it later

Comment: Yes!
Doesn't  $('#dataTable tr.selected td.id').html() or  $('#dataTable tr.selected').eq( COLUMN_NUMBER ).html() work?!

Comment: The Code you posted delivers in both cases undefined